# What precautions do I need to take in the event that my baby is born with Hemophelia?

Tags: newborn, health, family-planning

My wife and I recently got pregnant with our first child.

My sister-in-law's son is a Hemophiliac ([Hemophilia A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haemophilia_A)).  She's a carrier.  There's no evidence of the disease in the family before them, but that doesn't rule out the possibility of my wife being a carrier as nobody else has been checked.
My brother-in-law was born without the disease and is fine and healthy.

My sister-in law has been forced to go on Medicaid, with an income cap of $1600 a month, to afford the medication for this life endangering disease.

To prevent being stuck in the same situation if we had a son that had the disease, what precautions can we take?

My wife is due at the end of July.

Comment: Sounds like the best precaution would be to move to a nation with universal health care that offers those born there with citizenship.

Comment: @DA01: There might be some truth in your joke, but sarcasm doesn't come across well on the Internet...

Comment: @Beofett Makes sense. Comment withdrawn.

Comment: Wasn't meant to be sarcastic nor a joke.

Comment: @DA01 Sorry, I read it that way. Why don't you post it as an answer instead? Expand on it, so your reasoning gets clearer.

Comment: It was more of an empathetic statement. I know it's not a practical answer. It's definitely a frustrating situation and hopefully the US will eventually catch up to the rest of the world so that these types of issues aren't so stress inducing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would talk to a professional health insurance advisor concerning your health insurance (I *believe* your work is supposed to provide access to one as part of your health insurance). Bring every document you currently have, and make sure you understand exactly what your liability is, and what's on offer.

Secondly, talk to your local government and hospital officials about this, to see if there is any government support that could be available. They may be able to recommend charities and organisations who work with haemophilia.

Another thing you personally could do is talk to your sister-in-law, and find out if she knows of any organisations who have reached out to her that might be worth talking to.

Once you've got the information, write up a comprehensive plan of what you're going to do in the event of this happening. Use the time available **now** to think of what you're going to do when you're too tired and stressed to think.

Comment: I'm not up on current US health insurance changes that are in effect other than children can no longer be denied--but I don't think any sort of employer mandated providing of health care has kicked in yet.

Comment: No, but if they *do* provide healthcare, they're supposed to provide you with access to advisors. If they don't, then as with everything you take on yourself, you'll get less support.

Answer (score 4):

My daughter has cerebral palsy, and I have some chronic conditions that aren't a big deal alone, but the costs add up significantly when combined.

A lot depends on where you work.  If you work for a company that provides family insurance, your child is automatically enrolled, pre-existing condition or not.  That's generally not the case with plans that self-employed people use.

We make heavy use of a health savings account.  Those let you deposit a certain amount every paycheck tax-free, then they reimburse you for copays and other medical costs.

If your child is born with an expensive medical condition, the hospital will assign a case worker to help you with your options.  Before that, the best you can do is get good employer-provided insurance, and reduce your expenses to put some breathing room into your budget.

You might want to look into genetic testing to see if your wife is a carrier.  Also, once you know if you are having a boy, you could get an amniocentesis to test him.

Comment: +1 for using the health savings account as well as a flexible spending account if it's available.  Max is out and use it.